# filename expansion on assigning a non-array variable

Tags: zsh

This is about Zsh 5.5.1.

Say I have a glob pattern which expands to exactly one file, and I would like to assign this file to a variable. This works:

```
# N: No error if no files match. D: Match dot files. Y1: Expand to exactly one entry.
myfile=(*(NDY1))
```

and `echo $myfile` will show the file (or directory). But this one does not work:

```
myfile=*(NDY1)
```

In the latter case, `echo  $myfile` holds the pattern, i.e. `*(NDY1)`.

Of course I could do some cheap trick, such as creating a chilprocess via

```
myfile=$(echo *(NDY1))
```

but is there a way to do the assinment without such tricks?

Comment: Do you have a situation in mind where the distinction between `$myfile` and `${myfile[1]}` matters? I would just continue with the array assignment.

Comment: @chepner: Yes: If `myfile`is an array, `$myfile[1]` expands to the first element of the array (in this case just the file name). If it is a scalar, `$myfile[1]` expands to the first character of the file name.

Comment: That's not relevant since you *do* have an array. My question is, why *not* use an array?

Comment: @chepner. Exactly for this: I want to use this variable in the code later on, and I want to use it like any other scalar (including taking subscripts). From the viewpoint of maintenance, it is not nice to have to remember all the time, which variables are scalars and which ones are one-element arrays. Of course I can do a `myfile=$myfile[1]` and get rid of the arrayness, but the whole point of my question was to find out, whether Zsh, which is very rich in all kinds of constructs, offers some cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, zsh does not do filename expansion in scalar assignment, but the option [GLOB_ASSIGN](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOBASSIGN) could help. (This option is provided as for backwards compatibility only.)

```
local myfile=''
() {
  setopt localoptions globassign
  myfile=*(NDY1)
}
echo $myfile
;#>> something
```

Here are some descriptions in zsh docs:

> The value of a scalar parameter may also be assigned by writing:
>       `name=value`
>   In scalar assignment, value is expanded as a single string, in which the elements of arrays are joined together; filename expansion is not performed unless the option [GLOB_ASSIGN](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOBASSIGN) is set.
>
> --- [zshparam(1), Description, zsh parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Description-5)

---

> [`GLOB_ASSIGN`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOBASSIGN) <C>
>   If this option is set, filename generation (globbing) is performed on the right hand side of scalar parameter assignments of the form '`name=pattern` (e.g. `foo=*`'). If the result has more than one word the parameter will become an array with those words as arguments. This option is provided for backwards compatibility only: globbing is always performed on the right hand side of array assignments of the form `name=(value)` (e.g. `foo=(*)`) and this form is recommended for clarity; with this option set, it is not possible to predict whether the result will be an array or a scalar.
>
> --- [zshoptions(1), `GLOB_ASSIGN`, Expansion and Globbing, Description Of Options, zsh options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOBASSIGN)